# Adding Expression of JsonEqualTo to Ebean query

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a Ebean Query object and would like to add an Object of type expression to the where clause

```
query.where().add(Expr.jsonEqualTo(,,,))
```

Is there any way to do this?

```
query.where().add(Expr.eq(param, value))
```

is possible for example

I am using EbeanORM 6.8.1 by the way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you programatically want to add some conditions, you could write something like

```
ExpressionList<Customer> query = Customer.find.where().eq("name", "John");
if (condition)
    query.eq("lastName", "Doe");
query.findList();
```